# HashLocationStrategy in Angular2 rc3

Tags: angular

I know maybe this is an old question but since I could not find any answer for my problem. I have to post it again.
I am using Angular2 rc3, as far as I'm aware, I am using HashLocationStrategy

```
export const APPLICATION_PROVIDERS = [
 ...FORM_PROVIDERS,
 ...HTTP_PROVIDERS,
 ...ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
 { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
];
```

But I got no luck with it, app still provides routes something like "/app", "/home", no "/#/app" or "/#/home".
Someone please show me why, I can provide more codes if neccessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to add `APPLICATION_PROVIDERS` to

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [APPLICATION_PROVIDERS]);
```

AFAIR the syntax for `provide` was like this back then:

```
export const APPLICATION_PROVIDERS = [
 ...FORM_PROVIDERS,
 ...HTTP_PROVIDERS,
 ...ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
 provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
];
```

Comment: At first I thought this was nothing to do with my problem, but after some tweaks based on your answer, I finally figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your are not adding the `APPLICATION_PROVIDERS` const into providers key of a `NgModule`

First you need to import `APPLICATION_PROVIDERS` to the main entry of your application, then add it to the providers key in the `NgModule`

For example :

```
import {APPLICATION_PROVIDERS} from '.......';

@NgModule({
   .....,
   providers: [
     APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
   ]
})
class RootAppModule {}
```

Comment: I'm using version beta rc3 so still have no @NgModule yet.